# Does rich:extendedDataTable work in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I've found that the client-side dynamics for rich:extendedDataTable do not work for me in JSF 2 with either RF 3.3.3 or RF 4. Moving a column just causes the table to hand and the drop down for sorting doesn't drop down. Looking at the RF demo page of RF 4 I noticed that they do not demo sorting/filtering/column moving. Is this because it doesn't work in JSF2?

ref: http://www.richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection&skin=blueSky

Answer (score 0):

There is no header menus for sorting, show/hide columns in rich:extendedDataTable for RF4.0. They are planned for future release.  However, column re-ordering, frozen columns and lazy loading definitely works. I tried it myself.

You would like to implement sorting yourself by making header as commandLink and invoking toggle action of sorting order in backing bean.

Also, just for your reference, in RF4.0, you would not be able to save table state as well.

Few of the links which you would be interested in:

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&skin=blueSky

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10442